# OverlayItem Drawable moves after being clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, drawable, overlayitem

I have an app which displays icons a user can place and add details to. Recently I noticed, when a User clicks one of the icons, it moves down slightly. Any suggestions welcome !

**Before**
[image: before click]

**After**
[image: after click]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in myItemizedOverlay, I had an onTap method which displayed information about the point including it's icon.

When opening the dialog, I used a reference to the icon which was placed on the map.

The solution was to create an entirely new icon (Drawable) and use that instead of the reference.